# Where to put nginx configuration file?

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, vuejs2, html5-history

I understand that i should put this code in order to make HTML5 History fallback:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

but to which file? tried search google, nothing works, put above code in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf will make nginx not working.

im using vagrant Homestead for laravel.

please help.

Comment: Would you specify what is exact error you're facing?

Comment: Yes, that configuration should go in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.`

Comment: i put that code in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, and when i 'sudo service nginx restart' the error is 'Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.'

Comment: Run this command `less /var/log/nginx/error.log` & see what errors are there.

Comment: here is the error > 2017/06/17 01:24:59 [emerg] 1340#1340: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87 
> 2017/06/17 01:27:33 [emerg] 1369#1369: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87
> 2017/06/17 01:44:16 [emerg] 2851#2851: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i get nginx work with html5 fallback.

open /etc/nginx/site-available/homestead.app, or any domain your specified in your homestead.yaml file.

put/replace "location" section with

```
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```

then save, and open laravel web.php (router). put this code:

```
Route::get('/{vue?}/{vue2?}/{vue3?}', function () {
//    return view('welcome');
    if ( ! request()->ajax() ) {
        return view('index');
    }
});
```

above code prevent laravel to returning error 404. now vue html5 history fallback works without # sign.

thanks everyone for trying to help, without you guys i may not have any idea to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Put configuration in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
server { 
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
}
```

Comment: tried it, here is the error message: >2017/06/17 01:55:02 [emerg] 3408#3408: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:65
>2017/06/17 01:55:06 [emerg] 3420#3420: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:65

Comment: Just make sure `server {}` is below `events {}` above `http {}`.

Comment: @Ganesh, are events{} and http{} compulsory to run ?

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking for the location of the NGINX config file:

- The main config file is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.
- The default version of this file loads all files matching `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` into its `http` block.
- So if you want to specify a `server` block, you can overwrite `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` or add your own `.conf` file there.

Answer (score -1):

That is an entry for the `nginx.conf` file, located at

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add this to config:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Comment: here is the error when i put the code i mentioned in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > 2017/06/17 01:24:59 [emerg] 1340#1340: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87 > 2017/06/17 01:27:33 [emerg] 1369#1369: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87 > 2017/06/17 01:44:16 [emerg] 2851#2851: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66

Comment: I believe that goes inside the `http { }` section when running homestead

Comment: finally no errors, but html5 history fallback still not working

Comment: See the edit to my answer, it seems you don't need `$uri/`